# time.sleep prevents the previous line of code from executing

Tags: python, tkinter

Please help!:

I have a time.sleep(2) line of code in my code that is run after a Tkinter label is created. The label is not created. The time.sleep code prevents the label from being created.

The code:

```
youhaveregisteredlabel = Label(registerscreen.canvas, text='You have been registered', font=("Arial", 25), bg='#A9E2f3').place(x=0, y=375, width=600, height=150)
#creates a tkinter label widget called 'youhaveregisteredlabel' with the text "You have been registered" on it.

time.sleep(2) 
#creates a 2 second time delay

registerscreenback() 
#runs the registerscreenback subroutine, hiding the register screen and revealing the start screen.
```

Comment: Are you sure? there is no error in the `Label`  class that you might not have caught?

Answer (score 0):

Try to tk.update() before sleeping

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` does not prevent the previous command from executing. It prevents the UI from being able to refresh itself to show the results of the command. The command itself has run, but you're preventing tkinter from showing it.

Tkinter is single threaded, so while your own code is executing or sleeping, it cannot respond to events. That means not only events like button clicks, but internal events such as requests to redraw the window with new information.

As a general rule of thumb you should never call `sleep` in the same thread as the GUI code because it does just that: it sleeps.

If you must call `sleep`, or must call a long running section of code, you can explicitly force tkinter to refresh by calling the `update_idletasks` method common to all widgets.